# Reactive Streams - batching with timeout

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I am looking into replacing a homegrown log processing library which looks awfully close to ReactiveStreams with `io.projectreactor`. The objective is to reduce the code we maintain, and take advantage of any new features added by the community (eyeing operator fusion).

As a start, I need to consume the stdio and merge the multiline log-entries into text blobs that would flow down the pipeline. The use case is explained in detail on [multiline log entries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html) chapter of the Filebeat docs (except we want it inprocess).

So far the code I have is:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Flux<String> lines = Flux.generate(sink -> rethrow(() -> { while (true) sink.next(input.readLine()); }));
Flux<String> logRecordsStr = lines.concatMap(new LogRecordJoiner());
Flux<LogRecord> logRecords = logRecordsStr.map(new LogRecordMapper());
logRecords.doOnEach(r -> System.out.printf("%s payload: %d chars\n", r.timestamp, r.payload.length()))
          .subscribe();
```

This takes care about the multi-line merging when a new log header is detected, but in the existing library we also flush the accumulated lines after a timeout (i.e. if no text is received within 5 seconds, flush the record).

What would be the right way to model this in Reactor? Do I need to write my own operator, or can I customize any of the existing?

Any pointers to relevant examples and docs for achieving this use-case in Project Reactor or RxJava would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you seen `buffer(long timespan, TimeUnit unit)` operator(rxjava)?

Comment: Buffer looks really close, but none of the overloads matches what I need - I need a combination of "bufferClosingSelector" and "timespan" closing strategies - whichever happens first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you identify the start and end of each buffer, so the following RxJava 2 code is intended as a hint about using the main source's value to open and close the buffer's gate:

```
TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
PublishProcessor<String> pp = PublishProcessor.create();

Function<Flowable<String>, Flowable<List<String>>> f = o -> 
        o.buffer(o.filter(v -> v.contains("Start")), 
                 v -> Flowable.merge(o.filter(w -> w.contains("End")), 
                                     Flowable.timer(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES, scheduler))); 

pp.publish(f)
.subscribe(System.out::println);

pp.onNext("Start");
pp.onNext("A");
pp.onNext("B");
pp.onNext("End");

pp.onNext("Start");
pp.onNext("C");

scheduler.advanceTimeBy(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

pp.onNext("Start");
pp.onNext("D");
pp.onNext("End");
pp.onComplete();
```

Prints:

```
[Start, A, B, End]
[Start, C]
[Start, D, End]
```

It works by sharing the source via `publish` which allows reusing the same value from the upstream without having multiple source copies running at once. The opening is governed by the detection of a "Start" string on the line. The closing is governed by either the detection of the "End" string or a timer firing after a grace period.

**Edit:**

If the "Start" is also the indicator for the next batch, you can replace the "End" check with "Start" and alter the contents of the buffer since it will include the new header in the previous buffer otherwise:

```
pp.publish(f)
.doOnNext(v -> {
    int s = v.size();
    if (s > 1 && v.get(s - 1).contains("Start")) {
        v.remove(s - 1);
    }
})
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: How about the case where there is no END, but the buffer is closed when we see the next START, or a tumeout expires? I am starting to doubt my communication - is there anything that is not clear in the question?

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` operator seems most suitable and simple solution for me.

It has size and time based strategies.
You have log, so I think, you can interpret lines count as buffer size.

Here example - how emit items grouped by 4 or 5 seconds timespan:

```
    Observable<String> lineReader = Observable.<String>create(subscriber -> {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                subscriber.onNext(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

    lineReader
      .buffer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,4)
      .filter(lines -> !lines.isEmpty())
      .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I need the grouped by log header with tumeout. I.e. if I logged a 2-line message, followed by 1-line message, followed by stacktrace then another 1 line messshe and then nothing for the tumeout period. I would expect to get 3 messages immediately, up to the stacktrace, and a 4th message after the tumeout.